# copyobj copies entire image instead of axes only

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, plot

What I have is a plot showing the area of connected components. What I want to do is to further work on the plot figure such as clean it up a bit or `imcomplement` it etc. and then be able to apply the axes from the original plot to this image and be able to extract the `ylabel`.

Let me explain the above issue with my code and some examples.

This is the plot I have, the y-axis represents the object areas. This is the important axis that I want to transfer to the new image.

[image]

Since I am interested in the axes only I copy that using

```
h = findobj(gcf,'type','axes');
```

So that I can work with the figure without the axes and borders interfering I save it without these attributes

```
set(gca, 'visible', 'off'); % Hide the axis and borders
hgexport(gcf, 'plot1.jpg', hgexport('factorystyle'), 'Format', 'jpeg');
```

This is what I get:

[image]

So far so good.

Now comes the processing or in other words changing the plot to my needs.

```
plot_img = rgb2gray(imread('plot1.jpg'));
img_bw_plot = im2bw(plot_img, graythresh(plot_img));

[rows cols] = size(plot_img);

new = zeros(size(plot_img));

for i = 1: rows
    for j = 1: cols
        if (img_bw_plot(i,j) == 0)
            new(i, 1:10) = 255;
        end
    end
end

f = figure;

imshow(new);
copyobj(h,f)
```

This produces a weird overlapped image where instead of copying only the axes, the entire image is copied on top of the `new`. The `datacursormode` also fails to work beyond the over lapping image.

[image]

Comment: The reason the axes aren't on top of each other is because there is no guarantee in your code that they will be the same size or at the same position.  Get a handle to all the axes on your figure and check their position, you'll see that they are different.  Also, can you clarify that you understand that by copying the axes you get all axes properties, not just the data plotted in the axes.  (It's not clear, at least to me, that you understand that from your wording.)

Comment: I tried to make it the same size in my code, ``new = zeros(size(plot_img));`` Doesn't this make sure that the new image is of the same size as the plot I saved recently as ``plot1.jpg``. Also, you say that by copying axes, I get all the properties, not just the data plotted. I dont need the plotted data, I just need the ``Ylabel``. Am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: It's the position on the figure window that is different, not the size of your data set.  And yes, if all you need is the YLabel then just get it from your original axis and put it into your new axis.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am aiming at but all I get is this copy over of an image as shown above. Can you please tell me how can I just copy the ylabel onto my new axes? I tried that in my above code but clearly failed

Comment: You still need to be clearer about what you want.  Do you want the ylabel, which is a descriptive text string, and which you don't appear to have in your original image? Or do you want the YTickMarks and YTickLabels, which are the numbers up the left side of your axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I'm a little bit confused that if you have the figure in the first place why aren't you extracting your data from it using something like:

```
lines=findobj(gca,'type','line');
y=zeros(1,length(lines));
for i=1:length(lines)
  y(i)=get(lines(i),'ydata');
end
```

and there you'll have all the data.

But let's say the original figure isn't like a figure figure where you'd have access to the children of the axes object (though all of them being copied together kind of suggests that this is not the case). What you need to realize is that an "axes" object in MATLAB isn't just the axes of the graph, but the whole graph. For example when you have 5 subplots, each of those smaller plots is an axes object and the graph itself is one of its children which is a "line" object (refer to my example above).

So after this long lecture :), one solution is that you could manually create those axes around your newly drawn image instead of copying the axes object as such:

```
set(gca,'visible','on');
s=size(new); 
set(gca,'ytick',linspace(1,s(1),7),'yticklabel',linspace(6000,0,7));
```

This should do the trick of placing 7 ticks on the y-axis in the same manner as you have on your original figure. The same method would apply to manually creating the labels for the x-axis.

(I tried putting the resulting image here but I don't have the enough reputations to do so. That's on stackoverflow bro!)

Mind you, though, that this creates the labels on the graph giving you the illusion of the same axis while the actual coordinates of the points are actually determined by the size of the image you're saving. So if you want to make sure the image is the same size, you need to work on resizing your original figure to end up being the same size, which given then 0-6000, would be a really big image.